# How to search content in div and highlight the div title in which the content exists

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm new to asp.net environment and coding altogether. I've an asp.net View, in which I have a div which is bringing the data dynamically from the database. As below:

The content comes in the form of Title and then the content. As below:
"Content Title"
"Content"

[image]

I want to search the content on the page and highlight the title in which the content exists. And not the word searched for. Currently, when I'm searching any word, it's showing me the entire content in a particular color that I wrote in the code and it's also taking every letter in the search bar to search.

For example: Searchbar input is "test"
Content 1: "test image"
Content 2: "hello there"

So it is highlighting both the contents, because there is "e" and "t" in Content 2 too.

I tried jQuery filter function to search the typed input in div.

```
//Here is the Code.
<label>
    <div>
        <div class="filter-title">Search</div>
        <input id="search" type="search" class="inputbox" /></div>

   <script>
        jQuery("#search").on("keyup", function () {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        jQuery("#content_div *").filter(function () {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1).css('color', 'red')
        });
    });
   </script>
</label>
<div class="col-lg-12 acc-lastbor" id="content_div"></div>
```

The output I'm getting when I search the word "test" in the searchbox is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here complete solution (and also more generic way) with two different behavioural approach.

```js
$('input[data-filter]').on('keyup', function () {
  var target = $(this).data('filter');
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $(target).filter(function () {
    var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    $(this).toggle(text.indexOf(value) > -1);
  })
});
$('input[data-filter2]').on('keyup', function () {
  var target = $(this).data('filter2');
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $(target).removeClass('highlight');
  $(target).filter(function () {
    var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    return value != '' && text.indexOf(value) > -1
  }).addClass('highlight');
});
```

```css
.highlight{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Search</label>
<input data-filter="#content_div *" />
<label>Search (Color:RED)</label>
<input data-filter2="#content_div *" />
<div id="content_div">
  <div>t</div>
  <div>te</div>
  <div>tes</div>
  <div>test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried to do it the way you said but it turns out that the search itself is not working after I made the changes.

Comment: I edited my answer. I write more generic complete solution for you.